# Validate Form With PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code, where I want to have an array with the required fields, and only loop through the fields that are in the list.

```
                    //Required Fields   
                $validationFields = array(
                    "username" => "",
                    "email" => "",
                    "password" => ""
                    );


                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
                {   
                    $asd = in_array($_POST[$key], $validationFields);

                    echo "<pre>";
                    var_dump($asd);
                    echo "</pre>";

                    if(in_array($_POST[$key], $validationFields))
                    {
                        if($_POST[$key] == "")
                        {
                            $error = "has-error";
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Actually what is the problem? besides in_array($value, $validationFields) is enough to check.

Comment: I want to check if the fields from $_POST is in my $validationFields array, and if they are so, check if the $_POST values are empty. I only need a way to figure out how $_POST is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at `array_intersect` or for you needs `array_intersect_keys`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: Thanks, I got the check working, now I just need a way to see if the $_POST[$key]is empty, and $_POST[$key] == "" is not working, any idea?

Comment: Probably `if (empty($_POST[$key]))` is best.

Comment: I would add `isset()`. It can cause notice if array index is not set at all.